# Using splitGeometry in PyQGIS

Tags: python, qgis-3, splitting, pyqgis-3

Using QGIS 3, I'd like to [split a polygon](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Geometry/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.splitGeometry) using a line. My inputs are .geojson files, but that should be irrelevant:

Line:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "line",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 3.54692, 49.76417 ], [ 3.88975, 49.22462 ], [ 4.64133, 49.42229 ], [ 4.58858, 49.06073 ], [ 5.18193, 49.21601 ], [ 5.4852, 49.06937 ], [ 5.41927, 49.33644 ], [ 5.11601, 49.43086 ], [ 5.31379, 49.61916 ], [ 5.88077, 49.44801 ], [ 5.99944, 49.27626 ], [ 5.78847, 49.02616 ], [ 5.36653, 48.86162 ], [ 4.78637, 48.68782 ], [ 5.07645, 48.49596 ], [ 6.60598, 48.29459 ] ] } }
]
}
```

Polygon:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "poly",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 4.49628, 49.90025 ], [ 2.66349, 48.93096 ], [ 4.93141, 48.08362 ], [ 6.43456, 48.69653 ], [ 6.34227, 49.92572 ], [ 4.49628, 49.90025 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
poly = QgsVectorLayer(r"D:\SplitPoly\poly.geojson", "poly", "ogr")
line = QgsVectorLayer(r"D:\SplitPoly\poly.geojson", "line", "ogr")

polyGeom = poly.getFeature(0).geometry()
lineGeom = line.getFeature(0).geometry()

splitGeom = polyGeom.splitGeometry(line.getFeature(0), True)

print('Result:')
print(splitGeom)
```

You can also swap the 'splitGeom line' with:

```
splitGeom = polyGeom.splitGeometry(lineGeom.asPolyline(), True)
```

But either way the result is:

```
(1002, [], [])
```

Any suggestions what is wrong with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to split the polygon with the same polygon. You only use poly.geojson

Comment: Wow... a typical copy pasting issue.